# Merge two array of objects based on a key in Android Dart or Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter, dart

Array 1

```
[{ id: "abdc4051", date: "2017-01-24" }, id: "abdc4052", date: "2017-01-22" }]
```

Array 2

```
[{ id: "abdc4051", name: "ab" },{ id: "abdc4052", name: "abc" }]
```

I need to merge these two arrays based on id and get this using Java or Dart, may kindly anybody please help:

```
[{ id: "abdc4051", date: "2017-01-24", name: "ab" },{ id: "abdc4052", date: "2017-01-22", name: "abc" }]
```

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/groupBy.html and  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/mergeMaps.html

Comment: for example: `groupBy(listOne.followedBy(listTwo), (e) => e['id']).values.map((e) => e.reduce(mergeMaps))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> getMap() {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> listOne = [{ 'id': "abdc4051", 'date': "2017-01-24" }, {'id': "abdc4052", 'date': "2017-01-22" }];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> listTwo = [{ 'id': "abdc4051", 'name': "ab" },{ 'id': "abdc4052", 'name': "abc" }];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> result = listOne.map((e) => {
    'id' : e['id'],
    'date' : e['date'],
    'name' : listTwo.where((element) => element['id'].toString().compareTo(e['id'].toString()) == 0)?.first['name'] ?? ''
  }).toList();
  return result;
}
```